# How to exclude dependencies in Maven <reporting> plugins?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, reporting, pom.xml

How do I exclude dependencies from a reporting Maven plugin? The `cobertura-maven-plugin` annoyingly pulls in `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic` which causes mulitple SLF4J bindings warning during build and run. I tried inserting `<dependencies>` with `<exclusions>` to the plugin but maven for some reason does not allow that in the `<reporting>` section. Any help is appreciated. The relevant POM is below.

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
               <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `which causes mulitple SLF4J bindings warning during build and run.`? The classpath of plugins and the classpath for dependencies are separated so i don't understand this sentence? Can you show log output about what you mean?

Comment: `[ERROR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.`


`SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/vokuheila/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]`


`SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/vokuheila/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]`

`SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.`


`SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]`

Answer (score 1):

This is old but I'll give my solution in case someone else has this exact issue. In my poms I inserted the following

```
          <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Inside the definition for my Cobertura plugin. 
Cobertura is using 1.1.7 anyway (in my case) check your artifacts to confirm, you just need to explicitly tell maven to pull that version when creating the plugin otherwise it will still pull the conflicting version and display the error

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue including the "scope" tag inside logback dependencies.

This is my POM  section:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback-classic-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback-core-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```